# How does phone charger output current relate to input current?

Tags: power

Typically 1 charger takes a 120V input, and produces an output of 5V and 2A, so its power consumption is 10W. Theoretically a single power outlet (20A limit on breaker) can supply 120V * 20A = 2400W, which is 240 chargers connected to a single power outlet to overload it.

But one single charger can already deliver 2A, and each power outlet can deliver at most 20A... I am confused how these add up, because it seems like >10 chargers can already deliver more current than a single power outlet.

Comment: The relationship between DC output current, and AC current draw is nonlinear.

Comment: *"it seems like >10 chargers can already deliver more current than a single power outlet."* And that is perfectly fine, power adapters are capable of transforming **high voltage + low current** into **low voltage + high current**. So a 2 A load at the output of a charger does not mean there is also 2 A at the 120 V input. Fortunately !

Answer (score 1):

In a switching converter (which 99.99% of phone chargers are), the power going in and power going out is nearly the same, less a little bit for efficiency. So in a buck-converter with 120Vrms input, and a 5V, 2A output, the output is 10W and the input is ~11W (for a 91% efficient converter, let's just use that as an estimate). Therefore, if the input voltage is 120Vrms, the input current is 11W/120V = ~92mA.

So, yes, 20 adapters *can* deliver more total current than a single wall outlet, *but at a lower voltage*, so power is conserved (and physics is happy).

As an aside, I don't know if you plan to plug 240 USB adapter into a single circuit, but I don't recommend doing that. Additionally, 92mA is wildly optimistic. Check your USB adapter for its AC current consumption. I happen to have one in front of me with the following specs: INPUT 100-240V~50/60Hz **0.2A**, OUTPUT 5.1VDC 850mA. Which implies that plugging 100 of them into a single breaker is enough to cause trouble, among other things.

Comment: Input power equals to the output power plus loses. For all switching power supplies like those USB chargers, the loses are generally very less. That's why they heats up only mildly even during peak output operations. But as it is pointed out by uint138_t, the spec marking on the USB charger units indicate higher current rating than what it really should be for the given power output. This is because the spec actually stating the initial momentary inrush current d